# Galactic bars and star formation

Tags: astrophysics, stars, galaxies

I have recently been reading on barred galaxies and am confused as to whether they aid or obstruct star formation as a general rule. Some papers state that they aid star formation, whilst others suggest that they hinder it due to turbulence. From what I can understand, they aid star formation at the central bulge and hinder it in the inner disk by draining its gas.

There are papers which state that they increase instability and hence cause the bulge to assume a boxy/peanut shape. Is the B/P shape of a galactic bulge a direct result of the bar?